# Removing a playlist item that is a deleted or privated video

Tags: java, youtube, youtube-data-api

Also quickly just to note, yes I have searched quite a bit online for any solutions for this, but have only come up with a bug with removing from the 'watch later' playlist on YouTube. Perhaps it may be a similar bug with the API itself.

I have only just recently begun experimenting with Google APIs and the YouTube data API.

My goal was to clear up my "likes" playlist, which has about 1000 videos, and my idea of doing that was to fetch a list of playlist items, and then delete them one by one from the playlist, thus "unliking" them.

My little program was running perfectly fine, authenticating correctly through OAuth, and then running through each playlist item, until it encountered either a private or deleted video. (I assume the same would happen for a video that I am blocked from viewing.)

Here is the stack trace of the exception that is thrown:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 404 Not Found
{
  "code": 404,
  "errors": [ {
    "domain" : "youtube.playlistItem",
    "location" : "id",
    "locationType" : "parameter",
    "message" : "Playlist item not found.",
    "reason" : "playlistItemNotFound"
 } ],
  "message": "Playlist item not found."
}
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:146)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:321)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1065)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
    at YouAPI.V3ApiTest.removePlaylistItem(V3ApiTest.java:72)
    at YouAPI.V3ApiTest.run(V3ApiTest.java:30)
```

Here is my code. This is a stripped down version, and I crammed everything into one class, for the purpose of being able to post it here easier:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.services.samples.youtube.cmdline.Auth;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.YouTube;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.PlaylistItem;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.PlaylistItemListResponse;
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;

public class V3ApiTest
{
    private YouTube _youtube;

    public void run() throws IOException
    {
        List<String> scopes = Lists.newArrayList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube");
        Credential credential = Auth.authorize(scopes, "testing");
        _youtube = new YouTube.Builder(Auth.HTTP_TRANSPORT, Auth.JSON_FACTORY, credential).setApplicationName("testing").build();

        List<PlaylistItem> playlist = getPlaylistItems("<list>");

        System.out.println("Playlist size: " + playlist.size());

        PlaylistItem deletedVideo = playlist.get(251);

        removePlaylistItem(deletedVideo);
    }

    public List<PlaylistItem> getPlaylistItems(String playlistId) throws IOException
    {
        List<PlaylistItem> items = new ArrayList<>();

        YouTube.PlaylistItems.List request = _youtube.playlistItems().list("contentDetails,snippet");
        request.setPlaylistId(playlistId);
        PlaylistItemListResponse retrieved = request.execute();

        while (retrieved.getNextPageToken() != null)
        {
            items.addAll(retrieved.getItems());

            System.out.println("Retrieving playlist page '" + retrieved.getNextPageToken() + "'");
            request = _youtube.playlistItems().list("contentDetails,snippet");
            request.setPlaylistId(playlistId);
            request.setPageToken(retrieved.getNextPageToken());
            retrieved = request.execute();
        }

        // On the last page (or first if there is only one page), the code within the while loop
        // wont get called (because there is no next page) so add all of the videos in the retrieved
        // page and add them to the list
        if (retrieved.getNextPageToken() == null)
        {
            items.addAll(retrieved.getItems());
        }

        System.out.println("Sucessfully retrieved playlist.");

        return items;
    }

    public void removePlaylistItem(PlaylistItem item) throws IOException
    {
        System.out.println(item.getContentDetails() + ", " + item.getSnippet());
        System.out.println("Deleting playlist item '" + item.getId() + "' [video='" + item.getContentDetails().getVideoId() + "', playlist='" + item.getSnippet().getPlaylistId() + "'].");

        YouTube.PlaylistItems.Delete deleteCommand = _youtube.playlistItems().delete(item.getId());
        deleteCommand.setId(item.getId());
        deleteCommand.execute();
        System.out.println("Sucessfully deleted playlist item.");
    }
}
```

The 251st video in the playlist is a privated video, and that's why the 404 is thrown, however I don't understand why it says that the playlist item is not found, as I have just fetched it using the API.

Any other index that is not privated or deleted (like 250) will run perfectly fine, and will delete from the likes playlist.

---

**EDIT**

After a little bit more messing around, I found that private videos will delete perfectly fine in the playlist, however there is some type of video that almost seems to not even exist. These are my very first likes from when I first started my YouTube account, so my theory is that they just no longer exist... (somehow)
When calling the playlistItems.list resource in the YouTube API, it will return a JSON list of "items."
A normal entry in this list will look like this:

```
{
  "kind": "youtube#playlistItem",
  "etag": "\"uQc-MPTsstrHkQcRXL3IWLmeNsM/-E5SEVA1M-_RP2FgLOKwU1J3XGg\"",
  "id": "cHJpdmF0ZXBsYXlsaXN0Zm9ycHJpdmFjLnBJS3NIaDNCRlBJ",
  "contentDetails": {
    "videoId": "pIKsHh3BFPI",
    "videoPublishedAt": "2010-01-02T23:36:50.000Z"
  }
}
```

However the troublesome videos, which I have at least 50 of in my likes playlist, will return a very similar entry, except for a missing "videoPublishedAt" property:

```
{
   "kind": "youtube#playlistItem",
   "etag": "\"uQc-MPTsstrHkQcRXL3IWLmeNsM/lLin0muEkjiMnqxU6F0_hiAPQu8\"",
   "id": "cHJpdmF0ZXBsYXlsaXN0Zm9ycHJpdmFjLmVWSGNlNS0xcmVV",
   "contentDetails": {
     "videoId": "eVHce5-1reU"
  }
}
```

Based on this it feels like those videos don't even "exist" anymore. I'm sure they are very very very old...  I don't know if this is how deleted videos look like, but it really doesn't feel like it as they are titled "[Private video]" (you can tell based on the stacktrace above) and because when you go to them on the youtube watch page, it just says "This video is unavailable." Nothing to do with being deleted... or even being private.